# Laravel 4 passing parameters to Controller from Form in View

Tags: forms, view, parameters, controller, laravel

I want to save data to the database by clicking on a button in a view file.

I would like to achieve this by calling a method in my controller via POST.
It works but I have to pass some variables/parameters ( without having inputfields ) to the controller and that doesn't work.

this is my controller:

```
class CouplesController extends BaseController {
public function postCreate($var1)
{

    Couple::create(array(
        'name'=>'test',
        'id1'=>$var1
    ));

    return Redirect::to('couples')
        ->with('message','Your couple was created successfully!');

}
}
```

and this is my view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'CouplesController@postCreate', $var1->'hello')) }}

<p>{{ Form::submit('Create') }}</p>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

probably I'm doing this completely wrong. I just don't know how to do this.

btw it doesn't have to be the POST method.

Answer (score 0):

You are really close, within your view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'CouplesController@postCreate', 'hello')) }}

<p>{{ Form::submit('Create') }}</p>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

This will generate a URL similar to:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/couples/create/hello" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Then the rest of your code should work without an issue, and `$var1` should be set to the value of `hello`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't work, I get the following error message: Missing argument 1 for CouplesController::postCreate()

Comment: I think you might want to delete all routes specific to the `CouplesController` and use the [RESTful Controller routing](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) which Laravel provides, so the only route would be: `Route::controller('couples', 'CouplesController');`

Comment: okay I did this now and still receive the error: Missing argument 1 for CouplesController::postCreated()

Comment: please, still need help on this. maybe I have to fetch it not via Input::get('var1'); ?

Comment: Make this change: `public function postCreate($var1 = "test")` see if it gets rid of the error.  If it does, then you likely have an error within your view, it is not properly appending the variable to the form action.  Check the source of the form page and ensure it looks similar to the HTML I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that the error with the missing parameter appears while having this route:

```
Route::post('couples/done', 'CouplesController@postCreate');
```

when I take this route out it gives me this error:

> Unknown action [CouplesController@postCreate].

like it doesn't have access to the controller in the view itself.

:(